# No route matches [GET] "/admin/products" although there is one in rake routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

can I get your help on the error? I keep getting this one
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ5dO.png)

My routes 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzyox.png)

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'
  resources :products, only: :show
  
  devise_for :users

  devise_scope :user do
    authenticate :user, ->(u) { u.admin? } do
      namespace :admin do
        resources :products
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And Controller 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jONvJ.png)

```
class Admin::ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index; end
end
```

Comment: What does `bundle exec rails routes | grep admin` return in your project?

Comment: Are you logged in as admin?

Comment: Thank you, logging in as an admin helpt. But I don't understand why Pundit didn't redirect to the home page as my ApplicationController has it set   rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do 
    redirect_to root_url, alert: 'You do not have access to this page'
  end

Comment: That's a different error, than the one you encountered

Comment: Routes are checked before authorization